# Redirect in Slim

Tags: ajax, twig, slim

I have an ajax request, but I need my response to redirect to a certain twig template. This is what I have:

```
$response = ['success'=>false]; 
return $this->view->render($resp, 'spotlight-results.twig',['data' => $response] );
```

The problem with this is I am receiving the page in the console, this is not replacing the page that makes the request. I don't know if I explained myself correctly...

Comment: when you say "To redirect to a template" do you mean your ajax should send you html or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
 $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../templates/');
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
 $template = $twig->loadTemplate('spotlight-results.twig');
 $message = ['success' => false];
 $view = $template->render(['data' => $message]);
 $response = ['success' => false, 'view' => $view];
```

This way I return my template, with my desired content, $message